# Does $\nabla A \times \nabla B = 0$ imply that A is a function of B?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

As stated in the title. Assuming that A and B are both non-constant functions of $x,y,z$, does $\nabla A \times \nabla B = 0$ imply that A is a function of B, $A=A(B)$ in the sense that there exists a function $f$ such that $A = f \circ B$ ? 
If so, how could I go about proving it?

Comment: I think it would be better if you could clearly state what A and B are.

Comment: If $B$ is a constant function, then $\nabla A \times \nabla B = 0$ for any differentiable function $A$. Is $A$ a function of the constant function $B$? In what sense do you mean is $A$ a function of $B$?

Comment: You're right sorry, editing my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, If $A=\sin(x)$ and $B=0$ then of course $A$ is not a function of $B$ despite $\nabla A\times\nabla B = (\sin(x)e_x)\times 0 = 0$.

Actually you can have $A$ and $B$ be almost any function of $x$, I could have chosen $B=1$ or even $B=x^2$.

Comment: $A=\{\sin(x),0,0\}$ and $B=\{1,0,0\}$ works too and is less pathological feeling.

Comment: Good point, I should have been clearer in my question; I'm assuming that both $A$ and $B$ are non-zero.

Comment: @BenStokes Yes, but that doesn't improve anything. I don't even have to assume that any of $A$ and $B$ is constant.

Comment: I see what you mean, marking the question as solved. Thanks!